# Access-Control-Allow-Origin to domain itself. Is it OK?

Tags: vbscript, cors, http-headers

I have two domains which domain **B** is **parked** on Domain **A** and both of them are served from a single server with same content.

For some reasons I pass some of processes only to the  **B** So I need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for **A** to let it work with **B**. However as the domain **B** is parked on **A**, I will also have  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://A`   on the domain  A itself.

I can not find any resources what happens if I set CORS for a domain to itself? Does it make any security problem or limitations or stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what happens if I set CORS for a domain to itself?

It’s the same as not setting any CORS config at all — because browsers won’t ever consider a request to be cross-origin if it’s made from code running at the origin to any URL at the same origin.

So if you “set CORS for a domain to itself”, browsers will never allow code running at any other origin to access a response from there.

> Does it make any security problem or limitations or stackoverflow?

It creates no problems. It’s the same as not specifying any CORS config.